# Is it possible to make a graph eulerian by adding exactly one node?

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G=(V,E)$ denote a connected graph with $|V|\geq 2$. Is it possible to add a new node $v$ with corresponding edges $e_k=\{v,w\}$ with $w\in V$<sup>(*1)</sup> such that $(V\cup\{v\},E^\prime)$ contains an eulerian cycle where $E^\prime=E\cup\left(\bigcup\{e_k\}\right)$? Prove if possible; otherwise, show a counterexample.
>
> <sup>(*1)</sup> It is **not** mandatory to connect the new node $v$ to every other node. One is allowed to omit some of them.

**Thoughts.** Basically I think it is possible, however I don't know exactly how to argument. I was thinking about comparing the degrees of all nodes and when adding new edges connecting the new node to the old graph to argument when degrees get even/odd to show, that in the end it is possible that all nodes will have even degree, no matter which graph we had at the beginning. This is the result I got when adding one edge and inspecting that there can't be a circle, and obviously the degree of the new node is 1. That way I would have to add an even number of edges to achieve what has to be done.

**Question.** Can anyone give me some hints on how to start and what exactly to prove?

Comment: How many vertices of odd degree can a graph have? [Handshaking lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma)

Comment: This lemma and Michaels answer helped me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the property: A connected graph has an Eulerian path if and only if it has at most two vertices with odd degree.

Then look at the number of odd degree vertices in $G$, and figure out the correct edges to use to make $(V \cup \{v\},E^\prime)$ have at most two vertices with odd degree.

Edit: If you want an Euler cycle, then you must make $(V \cup \{v\},E^\prime)$ have no vertices of odd degree. We'd then want to connect the new vertex to every odd degree vertex in $G$ and then argue that the new vertex has even degree.

Comment: I know that a connected graph has an Eulerian path iff all vertices have even degree. I even proved that yesterday, isn't that contradicting with your mentioned property?

Comment: It has an Eulerian cycle iff every vertex has even degree. Paths are less restrictive.

Comment: I am sorry, then I have translated it wrong. I have to work with a cycle - editing it now!

Comment: This statement should also work for Eulerian cycles if you use the parity argument for vertices of odd degree. See Martin Sleziak's comment.

Comment: The handshaking lemma and your edit gave me a good clue to solve this. Thanks!